# Azure Pipeline configurations

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am facing a problem that is confusing me a bit and I would like to find the best approach to avoid to repeat my pipelines.

in this GitHub repos I have my yaml file to build the project, and this yaml targets a folder template on which it runs the C# Build and Publish. Approximately the GitHub repo is structure as follow:

```
- Folder 1
- Folder 2
- Folder 3
- Azure-Pipelines(build and Publish)
- Azure-pipeline.yaml
```

During the pipeline run, my yaml targets the Àzure-Pipelines(Build and Publish) folder and build the project. This is my Azure-pipeline.yaml file

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build'
  jobs:  
  - template: Azure-Pipelines/build.yaml
    parameters:
      solution: 'Solution-to-build'

- stage: Publish
  displayName: 'Release and Push'
  jobs:  
  - template: Azure-Pipelines/publish.yaml
    parameters:
      <All the parameters configured for this yaml file>
```

The template and the structure of my GitHub, keeps repeating themselves, as in each gitrepo I have that Azure-pipeline folder. What I am trying to to. Is to have a GitHub repo Where I keep the build.yaml and publish.yaml. and make `all` the other repos refer to this folder when the pipeline runs.

Is there any way how I can achieve this?

Please if I am missing any details to make my point clear, just ask. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Hi @Nayden Van. Is there any update about this issue? Feel free to let me know if the method could meet your requirements.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Thank you so much for you advice and help, I will shortly test it. right now I am struggling with a azure pipeline that fail to build my docker file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way how I can achieve this?

You could try to use the [Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-resource-definition) in YAML Pipeline.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create a **Github** Service Connection in **Project Settings -> Service connection** .

Step2: You could try to use the following sample to use the yaml template from another Github Repo.

**Example**

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: serviceconnectionname
    name: githuborg/reponame   #e.g. yy/test
    ref: main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build'
  jobs:  
  - template: Azure-Pipelines/build.yml@MyGitHubRepo
```